# hide button after 5 clicks jQuery | Localstorage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In short i want that if button is clicked more than 5 times , the button gets hide , by saving the clicks in localstorage so that when user login again he wont be able to see that button if clicked 5 times. i want to store the clicks in localstorage by jQuery method.
i have written some code, it was working fine before but i don't know what happened suddenly it stopped the button is not hiding now
my code below

```
               <script>//this script is responsible for adding a unique data-click= 0,1,2,3,4.....n to each resume post respectively.
            //  $(document).ready(function() {
                      var PostId = 2;
                         var i = 1;  
                    $('.gotocls').each(function() {
                      jQuery(this).attr('data-click', i);
                      var ClickId = $(this).attr('data-click');
                      var LocalKey = PostId + '+' + ClickId;
                      if(localStorage.getItem(LocalKey)){
                        if(localStorage.getItem(LocalKey) == '5'){
                          $(".gotocls").hide();
                        }
                      }
                      else{
                        localStorage.setItem(LocalKey,0);
                      }
                       i++ 
                    });
                //  });
            </script> 
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
             // $(document).ready(function(){
               $(".gotocls").click(function() {
                   var PostId = 2;
                  var ClickId = $(this).attr("data-click");
                 var LocalKey = PostId + '+' + ClickId;
                 count = localStorage.getItem(LocalKey);
                 count ++;
                   if(count > 4){
                            localStorage.setItem(LocalKey, 5);
                            $(".gotocls").hide();
                   }
                   else{
                     
                   }
               });
             // });
    </script>
```

and my html button code

```
<a  class="dkpdf-button gotocls" href="mysite.com">Downlaod Now </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this (I added a reset local storage link so you can test again, if you wish, by clearing the local storage.)

1. button will be hidden after you clicked 5 times
2. system is using local storage so will remember the number of clicks even the browser is closed

Codes are below:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  

    
<script type="text/javascript">
        
$(document).ready(function(){                       
              
              // Below is the click button
              
               $(".gotocls").click(function() {
                   var PostId = 2;
                 var LocalKey = PostId;
                 count = localStorage.getItem(LocalKey);
                 
                 count ++;
                 
                   if(count > 4){
                            localStorage.setItem(LocalKey, 5);
                            $(".gotocls").hide();
                   }
                   else{
                   localStorage.setItem(LocalKey, count);
                 alert("you have clicked: " + count);

                   }
               });
               
              // Below is the reset button
              
              $(".gotocls2").click(function() {
              var PostId = 2;
              var LocalKey = PostId;
              localStorage.setItem(LocalKey, 0);
              $(".gotocls").show();
               });
               
               
               
 });
 </script> 
    
    
<a  class="dkpdf-button gotocls" href="javascript:return false;">Download Now (test) </a>   
<br><br>
<a  class="dkpdf-button gotocls2" href="javascript:return false;">Reset Local Storage</a>   

<script>
var PostId = 2;
var LocalKey = PostId;
count = localStorage.getItem(LocalKey);
if(count > 4){
$(".gotocls").hide();
}
</script>
```

**Additional Codes** (for multiple download buttons)

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  

    
<script type="text/javascript">
        
 
function set1(var1){
var PostId = var1;
var LocalKey = PostId;
count = localStorage.getItem(LocalKey);

count ++;

if(count > 4){
    localStorage.setItem(LocalKey, 5);
    $('#' +var1).hide();
}
else{
    localStorage.setItem(LocalKey, count);
    alert("you have clicked: " + count);

}
}
 
 
function show1(var1){
    var PostId = var1;
    var LocalKey = PostId;
    count = localStorage.getItem(LocalKey);                
    if(count > 4){
    localStorage.setItem(LocalKey, 5);
    $('#' +var1).hide();
    }
} 
 
 
 </script> 
    
    
<div id=download1 onclick="javascript:set1('download1');";>Download Now (test1) </div>   
<br>
<div id=download2 onclick="javascript:set1('download2');";>Download Now (test2) </div>   
<br>
<div id=download3 onclick="javascript:set1('download3');";>Download Now (test3) </div>   
<br>


<a  href="javascript:localStorage.clear();alert('Done clearing local storage data !');location.reload();">Reset Local Storage</a>   

<script>

show1('download1');
show1('download2');
show1('download3');

</script>
```

Comment: okk so after adding you this script  alert("you have clicked: " + count); this is working

Comment: there are multiple posts and each post have unique downlaod button with unique data-click attribute id, when i click on downlaod now button of first post all the download buttons of other posts also gets hidden on only 1 click

Comment: If you have multiple posts, you need to have multiple lines of codes (with different PostID) for the click buttons --- (by a loop usually), or do it by passing the PostID thru a parameter. Please adjust the codes to suit your needs. But if you still have problem please let me know

Comment: well for that i added data click attribute for each downlaod now button now each downlaod now button have data-click="1" for post 1,   data-click="2" for post 2 and so on

Comment: look up my code once...can you please little bit modify my  code so that clicks will start working again\

Comment: I cannot just change your codes because if you have multiple post, it should be done by ID instead of class. I will revise my answer so you can try.

Comment: I have added the "Additional Codes" (for multiple download buttons). Please try .

Comment: Hi ,just follow-up. Did my answer solve your problem ?

Comment: yes thanks offcourse it helped me after some little modifications i was able to do that stuff ! thanks man i appreciate your help